# Windows 8 app deployment - create folders, copy files

Tags: c#, deployment, windows

I have a windows 8 app (store) that was built originally for windows 7. Previously our installer created a folder \appdata\roaming\company\ and placed some required files (xml,and a sqlite db file) in this folder.

These files and the folder are required for the app to run properly.

Question: is there a way to configure the app so it will create/copy these file when a user installs the app from the store?

Comment: Are you trying to access embedded file inside your app or are you trying to access file of a previous installed application?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can copy content file to a directory, you access the file embedded in your app using

```
await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(new Uri("ms-appx:///somedirectory/somefile.txt");
```

you then can write the file

```
W8StorageFolder W8Folder = new W8StorageFolder();
var W8file = await W8Folder.CreateFileAsync(filepath);
await W8file.WriteToFileAsync(data);
```

where data is an Array of byte in this case but there are probably other way to do that

note that there is no way to bulk copy directory so you have to copy all the file one by one or, has I done, you use a file list.txt from which you read all the files names to copy and you make it autogenerate this list file as a pre-build event

Comment: Ok, I was looking for a way for the "installer" to create the folder and copy the contents. So is the procedure to right click on the project -> add file. Then when the app launches the first time create/copy the required folders and files to %appdata%roaming? Or is the file added as a resource?

Comment: @user2479121 sorry I can't understand what you're saying. Anyway do you have to modify those file at runtime or are they static? if they're static you just have to access them using the ms-appx:/// protocol